# Polynomial convergence to zero

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_k $ be a series of n degree polynomials, that converges to $0$ uniformly in $[-M, M] $ for every $M$.

Say $f_k = a_{(0,k)} + a_{(1,k)}x +... + a_{(n, k)}x^n$

Prove that for every i, $a_{(i, k)} $ converges to 0.

It seems very very obvious to me,  but I can't prove it formally.. .  Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be the space of polynomials of degree $n$ on $[-M,M]$ with the norm
$$
\|f\|_{\infty} := \sup_{x\in [-M,M]}|f(x)|
$$
Now consider a different norm
$$
\|\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i \|_1 := \sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i|
$$
Since $V$ is finite dimensional, any two norms are equivalent, and so $\exists c >0$ such that
$$
\|f\|_1 \leq c\|f\|_{\infty}
$$
Thus, if $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, then $\|f_n\|_1 \to 0$, which implies that
$$
|a_{i,n}| \leq \|f_n\|_1 \to 0 \quad\forall i
$$

Answer (score 2):

Choose $n+1$ distinct points $x_0,...,x_n \in [-M,M]$. Let $X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^n
\end{bmatrix}$, and note that $\det X \neq 0$ ($X$ is a Vandermonde matrix).

Let $\phi_k = (f_k(x_0), ..., f_k(x_n))^T$, and $a_k = (a_{(0,k)}, ...,a_{(n,k)} )^T$. Then we note that $a_k = X^{-1} \phi_k$.

By assumption $f_k$ converges uniformly to zero, hence $\phi_k \to 0$, from which it follows that $a_k = X^{-1} \phi_k \to 0$.